# Get view of activity and fragments from service

Tags: android, android-activity, service, fragment

I have on my app a service who get my location (gps). This service get information like latitude, longitude, etc, and I want wrote these information in layouts fragment and activity (TextView).

But how can I get view reference of theses fragments since my service ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do one thing to achieve this. send broadcast to the activity. And on that activity where you want to update view register broadcast there. Once you get the location stuff then send broadcast. Hope that helps you. Write this code in service when you get location stuff and pass that stuff via intent as mentioned in below code

```
Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(your action here);
        broadcastIntent.putExtra(BaseBroadCastReceiver.BROADCAST_KEY_AUDIO_INDEX, audioIndex);
        broadcastIntent.putExtra(BaseBroadCastReceiver.BROADCAST_KEY_AUDIO_LIST, mSongList.size());
        sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
```

And in your activity write below code

```
 private void registerMyReceiver() {
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(your action here you passed in service);
    registerReceiver(playNewAudio, filter);
}
```

**NOTE: your action can be any string but string must be same on both side**

When activity's oncreate method is called, call registerMyReceiver() method
and in onDestroy method unregister is else you may get RUNTIME exception.

Below will be your code for actual broad cast receiver

```
 private BroadcastReceiver myBroadcast= new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //do your stuff here... get extra which you passed 
        // from service and set that value in views
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for you're response. How can I send broadcast to the activity ?

Comment: @Luzwitz, I have added code for your convinience if that helps you please don't forget to accept and upvote the answer

Comment: Yes, thanks you very much.
And how can I communicate with my service since my activity ? For changed values of variables for example...

Comment: for that you need to bind your service with your activity

Comment: Ok, have you an example for give activity context to my service ?